# Kubernetes - HTTPS Communicating between services

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, ssl-certificate, pki

I have few services running in multiple namesapces.

My deployment is as follows.

Ingress -> Service(ClusterIP) -> Pods

My application is running as HTTPS due to some restrictions and ingress also running as HTTPS. I have different certificates in both the places.

Trying to find different ways of communicating b/w services.

If both the services are running on the same namesapce,

1. Using ingress url  - This should be used for connecting from outside the cluster. But, still can be used within the cluster also.

> ```
> https://<INGRESS_NAME>.<NAMESPACE>.ing.lb.<CLUSTER_NAME>.XYZ.com/
> ```

2. Using service url

> ```
> https://<SVC_NAME>.<NAMESPACE>.svc.int.<CLUSTER_NAME>.XYZ.com/
> ```

3. Using just the svc name

> https://SVC_NAME:PORT

4. Using the svc name and namespace name

> https://SVC_NAME.NAMESPACE:PORT

Is there any other way of connecting?

Also, My application is running as HTTPS and Ingress is also with HTTPS.

When I connect using `https://<SVC_NAME>:<PORT>`, getting the cert error.

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name
> '<SERVICE_NAME>' does not match the certificate subject provided by
> the peer.

Do I need to include all these names( like URL 2, URL 3, URL 4) in the cert?